# How do I retrieve a Value from a KeyValuePair inside a List?

Tags: c#, list, contain, keyvaluepair

I have the following list and I need to run a Contains() or similar method on it to retrieve the value associated with a specific key. How would I do this? I've searched everywhere and tried many things but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> shopInventory = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
```

I would assume it's something along the lines of:

```
shopInventory.Contains((KeyValuePair<string, int>
```

If I've neglected to include any important information I'll be happy to provide it.

Comment: why are you using a list of KeyValuePair?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ.

```
return shopInventory.First(c => c.Key == key).Value;
```

You might want error handling on top of that too, of course.

You could also ToDictionary if you're using it a lot.

Comment: Thank you! I think I tried things similar to this but I didn't put in the ".Value". Everything works as intended now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Where(...)`

```
shopInventory.Where (kvp => kvp.Key == searchKey).Count() > 0
```

The above expression will return true if you at least one pair exist with the key equal to `searchKey`

If you want to do something with all of the pairs that match the supplied searchKey, then you can leave the `.Count() > 0` out and do something with the result of the expression.